# objective-c, getting the number of pages of a pdf document

Tags: ios, pdf, nsfilemanager, newsstand-kit

This might be a silly question but please help me out. I just want to know how to extract the number of pages of a PDF document saved on an issue's `contentURL` (Newsstand framework). In the must efficient way, because I just want number up correctly some thumbs of the pages I also have saved in the `contentURL`. In other words: Is it possible to know the number of pages of a pdf without open it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html

There is this method:

```
size_t CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(CGPDFDocumentRef document)
```

That gives you the number of pages.

Implement it as such:

```
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourPath];    
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
```